# Endomorphisms of the projective line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $f:\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a degree 1 endomorphism of the the projective line over $\mathbb{C}$.  It is well known that $f$ is an automorphism, and moreover it is determined by its value at three points.

Is there an analogous statement for endomorphisms $f:\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of higher degree? (I would like for $f$ to be determined by its value on a few points and some information about its ramification.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since your map $f$ is given by a rational function of the form $f(z) = \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$, with $p,q$ coprime polynomials of degree at most $d$, with the larger of the two having degree $d$.

Hence $f$ is determined by (for example) its zeros, its poles, and one other point (for a scalar multiplier), or $2d+1$ points in all (counting with multiplicity, and including $f(\infty)$).

Comment: The polynomials $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ definitely do not have to have the same degree: the only requirement is that the larger of their two degrees be $d$. For example $\frac {z^d}{1}$ or $\frac {z}{1+z^d}$ represent perfectly legitimate endomorphisms of degree $d$ of $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: Oops, yes, thank you - I was thinking homogeneously, as in ratios of sections of $\mathcal{O}(d)$, and forgot that the degree can drop when you dehomogenize.